# pyodbc vs ADO via COM for Python scripts

Tags: python, ado, pyodbc

For many years, my company has used the win32com module and ADO to connect to databases via ODBC in Python scripts.  I do not like ADO because it is ancient and because COM is inherently slow and because it tends to throw one particular exception for which there is no workaround I've ever found.  We use ODBC because we cannot assume that our customers have any particular database system (although most of them use PostgreSQL).  We have a class that wraps ADO and provides access to most (maybe all) of the functionality in ADO.  I am at a point where I could recommend a complete changeover to pyodbc.  Before I do that, I'm curious:  are there advantages to ADO via win32com?  Does it have more capability than pyodbc?

Comment: ODBC is actually *older*. It was [created by Microsoft in 1992](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_Database_Connectivity). ADO *is* OLEDB which *is* COM and both are Windows-only technologies. Unless you target Windows exclusively, you'll have to use ODBC. Neither is slow - performance is affected by each individual driver implementation. In fact, for decades the OLEDB driver for SQL Server was faster than ODBC. That's changed in the last 6 years and ODBC is considered the primary driver and is actually faster than OLEDB/ADO

Comment: We do target Windows exclusively.  My question was not about ODBC itself.  My question was about accessing ODBC through pyodbc or through win32com and ADO.

Comment: Why go through *another* technology? You should use ADO only if you intend to use the OLEDB drivers, eg to connect to Excel or Access. Otherwise you'd just be adding *another* layer on top of the ODBC driver. It's not OLEDB that's slow, it's going through two layers that causes the delay. Again, individual drivers may or may not offer all features or data types (eg spatial).

Comment: Panagiotis, thanks very much for taking the time to answer, but I don't think you are answering the question I am asking.  Our Python scripts connect to ODBC so that the same script can be used to talk to a PostgreSQL database or a SQL Server database or an Oracle database.  That is not going to change.  My only question is a comparison between pyodbc and win32com/ADO as the technique for connecting a Python script to ODBC.  Is one better than the other?

Answer (score 1):

> are there advantages to ADO via win32com? Does it have more capability than pyodbc?

Practically speaking, and specifically with regard to ODBC, not really. ADODB would have the advantage of being able to use an OLEDB provider for a database that had an OLEDB provider but not an ODBC driver, but that would be a rare occurrence. (The only such database I can recall is "SQL Server Compact Edition", which was discontinued long ago.)

As mentioned in the comments to the question, pyodbc would have the advantage of avoiding extra layers of middleware when communicating with the database, i.e.,

your Python app ↔ pyodbc ↔ ODBC Driver Manager ↔ ODBC Driver ↔ database

vs.

your Python app ↔ win32com ↔ ADODB ↔ OLEDB provider for ODBC ↔ ODBC Driver Manager ↔ ODBC Driver ↔ database

As also mentioned, win32com/ADODB is a Windows-only technology, whereas a pyodbc solution could also be deployed on Linux or Mac if the appropriate ODBC drivers were available for those platforms.